# Графика/Форма на Python3

Tags: python, gui

На чём быстрее делать форму для кода Питона?
Что можете посоветовать? Время ограничено, нужен инструмент, который будет лёгок в освоении.
Нужный функционал стандартен (кнопки, линии, медиа и т.д)

Comment: более развёрнуто опишите, что значит «делать форму для кода Питона»

Comment: то есть нужно просто создать форму для кода

Comment: в плане освоения Qt Designer сложен?

Comment: @user275027 для одних элементарен, для других неподъёмен.